# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":{} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, stack, react-native, react-navigation

Current Behavior
The app should redirect the user after loggin in or singin up to the homepage, but it throws this error instead

App.js :

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen } from './src/screens'
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'
if (!global.btoa) { global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

return (

<Stack.Navigator>
{ user ? (
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
{props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
</Stack.Screen>
) : (
<>
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
<Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
</>
)}
</Stack.Navigator>

);
}
```

Login.js

```
. . .
const onLoginPress = () => {
firebase
.auth()
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((response) => {
const uid = response.user.uid
const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
usersRef
.doc(uid)
.get()
.then(firestoreDocument => {
if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
alert("User does not exist anymore.")
return;
}
const user = firestoreDocument.data()
navigation.navigate('Home', {user})
})
.catch(error => {
alert(error)
});
})
.catch(error => {
alert(error)
})
}
. . .
```

Register.js

```
  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords don't match.")
        return
    }
    firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            const uid = response.user.uid
            const data = {
                id: uid,
                email,

            

fullName,
            };
            const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
            usersRef
                .doc(uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Home', {user: data})
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error)
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
    });
}
```

The error is cuased by this line in App.js:

```
{ user ? (
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
`   `{props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
</Stack.Screen>
) : (
```

**using these versions:
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.7",
**I updated "@react-navigation/stack" to 5.12.8
still same erorr

```
before it throws the error it gives me this warning
"Setting a timer for a long period of time"**
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is shown when you try to navigate to a screen that does not exist in your stack navigator, I see that you are trying to make navigation based on **user data** while this user value remains not updated **null**, as a result Home screen will not be added to the stack and react-navigation will show you an error.

I suggest we sort the code first and separate `AppNavigation` into a new JSX script as follows:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen } from './src/screens'
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'
if (!global.btoa) { global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

return (
  <AppNavigation/>
);
}
```

Then inside AppNavigation:

- Since you are using firebase there is no need to pass user data to the next screen, you can use `fire.auth().currentUser` to get your current user data.
- Also is have used `fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to listen for user state changes so whenever the user logs in it should get updated instantly and replace **Login & Register screens** with **Login screen** without the need for calling `navigation.navigate('Home', {user})` inside **onLoginPress**
- Last thing you have to create a **splash screen** to be shown to the user until verifing your user is logged in or not.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen } from '../src/screens'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import fire from '../config/Fire';
import Splash from '../components/common/Splash';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class AppNavigation extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn : null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.authListner();
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    // unsubscribe
    this.setState({
      loggedIn:null,
    })
  }

  authListner(){
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      //console.log(user)
      if (!user){
        this.setState({
          loggedIn:false,
        })
      } else if (user){
        this.setState({
          loggedIn:true,
        }) 
      }    
    }
    )
  }

  render = () => {
    if (this.state.loggedIn == null) {
      // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
      return <Splash />;
    }

      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
            {
              this.state.loggedIn == false ? (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />

                </>
              ) : 
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
                </>
           }

          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
}


export default AppNavigation;
```